# Is there a way to change the language in WordPress without plugins?

Tags: wordpress

I have a dynamic WordPress site , and I want to provide it in more than one language, I searched for a way to add the ability to change the language without plugins, and I did not find it.

Is there a way to make the site's language change when I add  `?hl=en or ?hl=en` in the link like this?

```
https://www.example.com/?hl=en
https://www.example.com/?hl=fr
```

using php

Thanks

Comment: it can be done, but honestly, it's a bloodbath: https://translatepress.com/wordpress-multi-language-without-plugin/

Comment: @GrafiCode I edited my answer to account for overcomplicated edge-case solutions too ;) bloodbath it a great word choice here, but I shouldn't have been speaking in absolutes. I always say, when writing software anything is possible, it's our job to know what's practical.

Comment: @TCooper I agree, and yes practicality must be taken into account, especially when the official documentation openly suggests the use of community developed plugins.

Comment: @GrafiCode Just curious, do you (or OP) know of any cases where not using a plugin is more ideal than using one? Wracking my brain but can't come up with any.

Comment: @TCooper I had a situation like that when the GDPR laws came out (cookie consent / cookie blocking), spent weeks looking for a suitable plugin and couldn't find any. I ended up custom developing the feature (in form of a custom plugin by the way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not currently a way to accomplish this without plugins, other third-party tools, or significant custom development. It is outside the scope of the framework. However, is there any reason you don't want to use a plugin? There are many great options, many free. If you see the link below, those free options listed in my quote include a link to the plugins for easy access.

[From the documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/multilingual-wordpress/):

> WordPress does not support a bilingual or multilingual blog
> out-of-the-box. There are however Plugins developed by the WordPress
> community which will allow you to create a multilingual blog easily.
>
> Creating a mulitlingual blog is basically installing WordPress in more
> than one language and letting the Plugin switch between them. This
> includes installing .mo languages files which most Plugins will
> require you to do manually. See Installing WordPress in Your Language
> for details.
>
> The free WPGlobus, Polylang, qTranslate-X, xili-language or
> Sublanguage plugins are installable on standalone WordPress sites. For
> multisite WordPress (one website per language), you can try Multisite
> Language Switcher, Zanto or Multilingual Press or purchase WPML.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below step:

1. Log in to your WordPress dashboard and go to Settings>>General.
2. In the Site Language dropdown list, select the language you want to use.
3. Click Save Changes.